# Repository Test in spring boot leads to Unknown entity Exception

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing, junit4

> - com.mohendra.user
>
>   - server
>
>     - Application.class //Main class
>   - package2
>   - package3
>
>     - domain
>
>       - Campaigns.class
>       - SmsDomainPackage.class
>     - repository
>
>       - CampaignRepository.class

The above is my folder structure, I am tryring to test CampaignRepository using spring dataJpaTest ,
I have written the following test

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mohendra.user")
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = SmsDomainPackage.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@DataJpaTest
@RestClientTest
public class CampaignRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private CampaignRepository repository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void findByCode() {
        Campaigns campaigns = new Campaigns();
        campaigns.setName("Name");
        campaigns.setCode("HELP123");
        campaigns.setStartDate(new Date());
        campaigns.setEndDate(new Date());
        this.entityManager.persist(campaigns);

        Campaigns campaigns1 = repository.findByCode("HELP123");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The test gives an exception of

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity:
>   com.mohendra.user.package3.domain.Campaigns

I have also used @ComponentScan as you can see, and I've also used @EntityScan to try scan entities from packages, but both of them dont work.
I cannot change my folder structure to make it standard, as it is not my project. Is there a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

The Application class should be in the root package. That way you will not need any @CompontenScan or @EntityScan because Spring Boot scans everything below your root package

Therefor I recomment to put `Application.class` in the package `com.mohendra.user`

And you have to decide which test slice you want. You have three:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@DataJpaTest
@RestClientTest
```

But I assume that you only want `@DataJpaTest`

Comment: I can't do so, it's not my project as i mentioned. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: I updated my answer because I saw that you have multiple test annotations on your test. You should read about testing in Spring Boot is working: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: What? It's just moving a class in another package. And this would be Spring Boot standard. It's a change for the better.

Comment: I've read it, but my understanding is that, @springboottest is to scan run the test in app context, but then u put datajpattest to test entities, and restclient for the rest template, is it wrong to put all three?

Comment: Yes it's wrong because for example DataJpaTest only starts minimal repositories and in-memory db where as SpringBootTest startes the whole environment.